# passing to children all state and props in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-5, ecmascript-2017

I have the following code on my render:

```
<TourHeader key="TourHeader" {...this.props, ...this.state} />
```

I get the following error:

```
Syntax error: Unexpected token, expected }
```

Only this was working:

```
<TourHeader key="TourHeader" {...this.props} />
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: how does you state look like ?

Comment: it's just a simple few states, and props

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can spread them separately:

```
<TourHeader key="TourHeader" {...this.props} {...this.state} />
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Answer (score 0):

You need to split them up into separate attribute spreads, eg:

```
<TourHeader key="TourHeader" {...this.props} {...this.state} />
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you first look up what the spread operator does in javascript.
Then you will realize the mistake you did. What you want is passing props and state to the child component. Do that separately like this.

```
<TourHeader key="TourHeader" {...this.props} {...this.state} />
```